# "Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls" in Meteor Method test

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm learning Meteor following basic "Todo tutorial" from official website. I have problem with the "Testing" step.
I have basic test of one Method, it looks like this:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    describe('Tasks', () => {
        describe('methods', () => {
            const userId = Random.id();
            let taskId;

            beforeEach(() => {
                Tasks.remove({});
                taskId = Tasks.insert({
                    text: 'test task',
                    createdAt: new Date(),
                    owner: userId,
                    username: 'tmeasday',
                });
            });

            it('can delete owned task', () => {
                const deleteTask = Meteor.server.method_handlers['tasks.remove'];

                const invocation = { userId };
                deleteTask.apply(invocation, [taskId]);
                assert.equal(Tasks.find().count(), 0);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

This test fails with error:

```
Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.
    at AccountsServer.userId (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:82:13)
    at Object.Meteor.userId (packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js:257:19)
    at Object.Meteor.methods.tasks.remove (imports/api/tasks.js:37:35)
    at Test.<anonymous> (imports/api/tasks.tests.js:27:28)
    at run (packages/practicalmeteor:mocha-core/server.js:34:29)
    at Context.wrappedFunction (packages/practicalmeteor:mocha-core/server.js:63:33)
```

IMO, this error message is controversial, because it says about mistake I didn't make, because as I can see from line 4 in the error message, stacktrace points to the Method declaration body, this one:

```
'tasks.remove' (taskId) {
        check(taskId, String);

        const task = Tasks.findOne(taskId);
        if (task.owner !== Meteor.userId()) { // <- ERROR MESSAGE POINTS TO THIS LINE
            // If the task is private, make sure only the owner can delete it
            throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
        }

        Tasks.remove(taskId);
    },
```

There is 1 difference between tutorial code and my one: I removed the condition `!todo.private` from my `if` statements, so in the original tutorial they look like this:
`if (!task.private && task.owner !== Meteor.userId()) {...`
IMO, this change makes the test reach the expression where it fails, because with the original code the test passes.

I also mentioned that changing `Meteor.userId()` to `this.userId` makes the test pass and the app also looks to work like before.

So, my question basically is: why the error message shows me controversial (IMO) info and what is the difference between using `this.userId` and `Meteor.userId()` in Methods?

My full "Todo tutorial" project code can be found at: https://github.com/kemsbe/simple-todo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically this.userId uses the `this` context of the function and Meteor.userId() uses the current fiber to get the userId.

If you want your code to work with Meteor.userId(), you need to run your function in a fiber. Another thing you can do is to stub meteor.userId, like explained in [How to unit test a meteor method with practicalmeteor:mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41316635/how-to-unit-test-a-meteor-method-with-practicalmeteormocha)