# How to fake a user in unit tests in Meteor using practicalmeteor:mocha?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor, mocha.js

I'm having a difficult time trying to test a methods in meteor that requires a connected user.  Basically I need to test if a user of the app can add an article to it's cart.  The methods will tests if a user is connected and, in order to test that will use Meteor.userId().  This seems to be a problem in unit testing as I get the error:
"Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls or publications."

So far, I tried to do what's proposed in this post: [How to unit test a meteor method with practicalmeteor:mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41316635/how-to-unit-test-a-meteor-method-with-practicalmeteormocha) but I don't understand what the solution is doing.

Here is my testing method:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Random } from 'meteor/random';
import { assert } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';
import { sinon } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:sinon';

import { Carts } from '/imports/api/carts/carts.js';
import { Articles } from '/imports/api/articles/articles.js';

import '/imports/api/carts/carts.methods.js';

import { SecurityEnsurer } from '/lib/security/security.js';

function randomInt (low, high) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low) + low);
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  describe('Carts', () => {
  describe('methods', () => {
    let currentUser;

    beforeEach(() => {
      Factory.define('user', Meteor.users, {
        name: "userTest",
        currentUser: {
          email: 'user@shop.info',
          password: '123456',
        }

      });

      currentUser = Factory.create('user');
      sinon.stub(Meteor, 'user');
      Meteor.user.returns(currentUser);

      Articles.remove({});

      articleId = Articles.insert({
        name : "azerty",
        description : "descTest",
        modelNumber : "wxcvbn",
        categoryName : "CatTest",
        price : 1,
        advisedPrice: 2,
        supplierDiscount : 0,
        brandId : "BrandTest",
        isAvailable: true,
        restockingTime: 42,
        color: "Yellow",
        technicals: [
          {
            name : "GPU",
            value : "Intel"
          },
        ],
      });

      Carts.insert({
        owner: currentUser,
        entries: [],
      });

    });

    afterEach(() => {
      Meteor.user.restore();
      Articles.remove({});
      Carts.remove({});
    });

    it('can add article', () => {
      let quantity = randomInt(1,50);

      const addArticleToCart = Meteor.server.method_handlers['carts.addArticle'];

      const invocation = {};

      addArticleToCart.apply(invocation, [articleId, quantity]);

      assert.equal(Cart.find({owner: currentUser, entries: {$elemMatch: {articleId, quantity}}}).count(), 1);
      });
    });
  }); 
}
```

If anyone can help me find out how to create my test, this would realy help me.

Answer (score 1):

To fake a user when calling a Meteor Method, the only way I found is to use the `mdg:validated-method` package which provide a framework around Meteor methods. This framework seems to be the standard now (see the [Meteor guide](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#validated-method)), but it requires to re-write your methods and the in-app calls.

After describing the methods using this framework, you are able to call them with the userId parameter when testing, using this kind of code (which verifies that my method is returning a 403 error):

```
assert.throws(function () {
    updateData._execute({userId: myExternalUserId}, {
        id: dataId,
        data: {name: "test"}
    });
}, Meteor.Error, /403/);
```

FYI, here are the packages I add when I do automated testing (Meteor 1.6 used):

```
meteortesting:mocha
dburles:factory
practicalmeteor:chai
johanbrook:publication-collector
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I set up a fake logged in user for testing publish and methods:

1) create a user

2) stub i.e. replace the Meteor.user() and Meteor.userId() functions which return the current logged in user in methods

3) provide that user's _id to PublicationsCollector, which will send it in to your publish function.

Here's how I did it, I hope you can adapt from this:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Factory } from 'meteor/dburles:factory';
import { PublicationCollector } from 'meteor/johanbrook:publication-collector';
import { resetDatabase } from 'meteor/xolvio:cleaner';
import faker from 'faker';
import { Random } from 'meteor/random';
import { chai, assert } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
// and also import your publish and collection

Factory.define('user', Meteor.users, {
    'name': 'Josephine',
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    describe('Menus', () => {
        beforeEach(function () {
            resetDatabase();

            const currentUser = Factory.create('user');
            sinon.stub(Meteor, 'user');
            Meteor.user.returns(currentUser); // now Meteor.user() will return the user we just created

            sinon.stub(Meteor, 'userId');
            Meteor.userId.returns(currentUser._id); // needed in methods

            // and create a Menu object in the Menus collection
        });

        afterEach(() => {
            Meteor.user.restore();
            resetDatabase();
        });

        describe('publish', () => {
            it('can view menus', (done) => {
                const collector = new PublicationCollector({ 'userId': Meteor.user()._id }); // give publish a value for this.userId
                collector.collect(
                    'menus',
                    (collections) => {
                        assert.equal(collections.menus.length, 1);
                        done();
                    },
                );
            });
        });
    });
}
```

You can also write a test for calling a Meteor method that relies on Meteor.userId():

```
expect(() => { Meteor.call('myMethod'); }).to.not.throw(Meteor.Error);
```